# Gradle install testJar to mavenLocal

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I'm currently building a source jar and a test jar.

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: 'maven'

configurations {
    testArtifacts
}

task testJar(type: Jar) {
    classifier = 'test'
    from sourceSets.test.output
}

artifacts {
    testArtifacts testJar
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    jcenter()
}
```

I can create the jars by executing

```
gradle :util:build
gradle :util:testJar
```

However, when I run `gradle :util:install`, only the library jar `<company><name><version>.jar` is installed to `mavenLocal()`, and the `<company><name>-test-<version>.jar`

How can I

- link the targets so I build the `testJar` target by executing `gradle :util:build` without the `:util:testJar` target?
- install the `testJar` artifact to `mavenLocal` by running `gradle :util:install`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Gradle `install` command installs jars in the artifacts block with the archives tag.

To deploy the tests jar, add it as to `archives` instead of, or in addition to `testArtifacts`.

```
artifacts {
    archives testJar
}
```